# Autoconnect bluetooth keyboard

Tags: keyboard, bluetooth

I have a bluetooth mouse and a bluetooth keyboard paired under Ubuntu 22.10. They work fine. When I boot the computer and both devices are switched on, the mouse is automatically activated; the keyboard has to be switched on by clicking on the bluetooth icon at the top of the screen, going to the "Bluetooth 3.0 Keyboard" entry that is shown and then clicking on the "Connect" button.
So why does the mouse connect automatically, whilst the keyboard doesn't? How can I get the keyboard to connect automatically?

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution myself:

First, open bluetooth settings and note the bluetooth address of the device (6 pairs of hexadecimal digits separated by colons, e.g. 01:23:45:67:89:AB)

Then open a terminal e.g. with Ctrl+Alt+T

Enter bluetoothctl

Enter trust 01:23:45:67:89:AB (i.e. the device's bluetooth address)

When the system confirms that it now trusts the device, enter exit.

Next time you start, the device will connect automatically.

Comment: You can set trust in Bluetooth settings without using a terminal.

Comment: Where? All I see is a "Connect", "Connected", "Type" and "Address". Before i used the terminal to trust the keyboard, clicking on "connect" had no effect.

Comment: It depends on DE. I don't have Ubuntu with Gnome on a real hardware, so I can't test it. In XFCE there is a "Trust" button in device properties. Try to right-click a device.

Comment: Right clicking a device had no effect. I tried other flavours of Ubuntu (K/L/Xubuntu) but they were worse! I flagged this problem in 2014,when I started trying out Ubuntu, and it still hasn't been fixed. So I'll return to Windows that never had the problem!

Answer (score 0):

For some reason the steps above weren't successful.
I had to connect, set an alias and then it started to work properly

```
[bluetooth]# connect 50:E6:76:A6:88:65
Attempting to connect to 50:E6:76:A6:88:65
[CHG] Device 50:E6:76:A6:88:65 Connected: yes
Connection successful
[CHG] Device 50:E6:76:A6:88:65 ServicesResolved: yes
[Bluetooth Keyboard]# set-alias bkeyb
[CHG] Device 50:E6:76:A6:88:65 Alias: bkeyb
Changing bkeyb succeeded
```

And now in the logs I see that the device is connected automatically every time I switch it on.